# Get user last login time on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to check which users login a sharepoint site during the past 30 days? and what's the last login time?

from my search, we could enable the auditing for the 'document view' for the site, then query the audit log. However, this may use lots of resource.

Is there a better way to do this using sharepoint powershell directly without creating extra webpart?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, SharePoint doesn't store this. I suggest you create a HTTPModule and log all requests in you own database. By doing this you can create all reports you need in an easy way.

Edit: If it's SharePoint 2010, you can enable Site usage statistics. After this you can access the SharePoint database and retract the data you want. The data won't be up to date though, it's a timer job filling the data so you can't really know what happened after the job ran. But if you only wants to create a nightly report, this is ok I guess.

The timer job was the reason we had to create http modules to always have correct live data.

Answer (score 0):

As Joakim said you can create custom HttpModule or query WSS_Logging db depending on your requirements. However there are still other approaches.

1. If you need data only about access through browser you can create
   delegate control and make own log.
2. Depending on your authentication setup you can create code with
   handling authentication events.
3. Using 3rd party analytic solutions (Google, Piwik, etc).